# how to two way binding concept using in dropdown in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I Have doubt how to two way bind concept using in dropdown button I tried but its not working.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...

Comment: @smnbbrv why Invalid HTML?

Comment: The closing option tag has two times >>

Answer (score 0):

Two way binding means you just need to bind with `[(ngModel)]` with your variable like this in your code (If required then you can use local variables in template like you used as `#businesstype`, else remove it)  -

```
<select class="form-control" id="business_type" required [(ngModel)]="update.business_type" name="business_type">
  <option disabled>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.method}}</option>>
</select>
```

[working example with demo entries](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xqgk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)